# add title to datepicker holiday array

Tags: datepicker, android-datepicker, android-date

Is there a way to add custom `titles` to the array so that each `holiday` has it's own `title` instead of the generalized `Date Unavailable`?

```
var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
var unavailableDates = ["2012/11/12","2012/11/22","2012/12/25","2013/01/01","2013/01/21","2013/02/18","2013/05/27","2013/04/04","2013/09/02","2013/10/14","2013/11/11","2013/11/28","2013/12/25"]; // yyyy/MM/dd 
var unavailableDays = ["Saturday","Sunday"];

function unavailable(date) {
ymd = date.getFullYear() + "/" + ("0"+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0"+date.getDate()).slice(-2);
day = new Date(ymd).getDay();
if ($.inArray(ymd, unavailableDates) < 0 && $.inArray(days[day], unavailableDays) < 0) {
   return [true, "enabled", "Select Date"];
 } else {
      return [false,"disabled","Date Unavailable"];
 }
}
$('#transfer-date').datepicker({beforeShowDay:unavailable, showOn: 'button', buttonImage: '../../images/icon-calendar.png', buttonImageOnly: true,});
```

Comment: Don't forget to add tags showing what language you are referring to.

Comment: Sorry - first time - strictly javascript/JQuery in a standard html environment.